# Swapping data in array after fetch from network

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view that uses an array for the underlying data. When loading, I read a saved copy of the data from disk while kicking off a network request to download fresh data.

When I click on the tableview, a property is set in one of the objects which is later used.

My problem is, if my timing is correct I can tap on the row and have the objects change so that the property is set on the old object, now my newly swapped object doesn't have that tap..

I'm looking for what would be the correct pattern to make this swap.. Not posting code as I feel it's more of a design issue..

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, my personal approach will be either of the 3 options:

1) Inform the user that there is new data available once your background fetch is complete and simply reload the whole table with fresh table when the user wants to.

2) Disable interaction on the loaded data and display a loading indicator to inform the user that data is being updated and refresh with the new data

3) Swap out the data when the user comes back from visiting a detail view. So initially you show the cached data in your tableview, when the user visits a detailview and comes back, display a loading indicator for a while and swap out the data.

Either of the options I think its super important to inform the user that some sort of change is about to happen.